# Importing a class from a module in python 2, causes an unknown "self"

Tags: python, class, module, self

I have 2 python files. One which declares a class called language:

```
class language:
    def __init__(self, name, letters, elements, grammar):
        self.n = name
        self.l = letters
        self.e = elements
        self.g = grammar
```

I saved this as : "language_class.py" . Then I tried to import it into another program called "turkish.py" by doing the following:

```
turkish = __import__('language_class').language(self,"Turkish",turkish_latin,turkish_grammar).turkish
```

When I run language_class.py I get no problems but when I run turkish.py:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmet\Desktop\Google Apps\transalator\The Transalator\Recources\Languages\turkish.py", line 1, in <module>
    turkish = __import__('language_class').language(self,"Turkish",turkish_latin,turkish_grammar).turkish
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

However self is clearly defined. Is this some sort of bug, or am I doing it wrong?
Thanks for your help, even if I just thanked you several hours earlier than you even seeing this message :D

Comment: You shouldn't need the "self" parameter in the module import line as it is implied I believe

Comment: `self` clearly is *not* defined; it's a parameter to `language.__init__`, and as such is not visible in the scope where you to set the value of `turkish`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to pass in `self`; python provides that *automatically* to methods.

You really also don't want to use the `__import__()` function if you can help it. Just do:

```
import language_class

turkish = language_class.language("Turkish", turkish_latin, turkish_grammar).turkish
```